# about R program path in Mac equivalent to Windows

Tags: r

How can we find the R file path in Mac ? 
In Windows, this should be C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\r   .

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R is not correct??

Comment: Try running `R.home()` to get the R executable path.

Comment: It returns a different value if you are running it on a Mac. It returns the path to the currently running R. You can have multiple version R installed and running on a single computer. There is no "one" path to R for any system really. You can install it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/R.app is where it is "installed" by default, assuming you want the executable or program or app mac style the underlying Unix system is as you stated /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R

Comment: I want to change C driver in Windows to Mac version
    
      local rpath  `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\r"'
       local roptions `"--slave"'
      tempfile tempsource templis